# go install does not recognize "-o" flag

Tags: go

I'm trying to do a `go install` and rename the output with the `-o` flag.

```
go install -o bar.exe src/foo.go
```

But this fails with the error:

```
flag provided but not defined: -o
usage: install [build flags] [packages]
```

`go help build` shows `-o` as the correct build flag to rename the output binary. There is no mention that this flag is not defined for `go install`.

`go run -o bar.exe src/foo.go` fails with the same error.

`go build -o bar.exe src/foo.go` works. I get bar.exe.

So is this just an error of documentation, or have I missed something?

My version: `go1.5 windows/386`.

Thanks.

Comment: The `-o` flag isn't defined for `install` or `run`. What's the error in documentation?

Comment: `go help install` gives `usage: go install [build flags] [packages]` so it seems reasonable to assume that any flags defined for `go build` are accepted here.

Comment: `go build -h` lists `The build flags are shared by the build, clean, get, install, list, run,
and test commands:` only after -o and -i are described. `-o` is not one of the shared build flags.

Comment: If you read the output of `go help build`: The build flags section starts with `The build flags are shared by the build, clean, get, install, list, run,
and test commands:`, and `-o` is not listed there.

Comment: @JimB That was my mistake. Next time, I'll RTFMC (the C is for closely)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`go build` accepts the `-o` flag but `go install` does not.

`go install` will always output to `$GOPATH/bin`

If you want to install a custom binary name to your gopath you can do `go build -o $GOPATH/bin/whatever` and that will be roughly equivalent to `go install`

Comment: `go build` isn't the same, because it discards all compiled artifacts after the binary is built. It's usually recommended to favor `go install`.

Comment: @JimB `go build -i` will save dependency artifacts in the `pkg` folders.

Comment: ah yes, forgot about that.

Comment: @captncraig Thanks, this works just fine. I reread `go help build` and realized that both the `-o` and `-i` flags are described above the line:
`The build flags are shared by the build, clean, get, install, list, run,
and test commands: 
<list of build flags>`
The wording was just vague enough that I didn't realize the preceeding flags were excluded.

Comment: this is a mistake by go authors ... go install should accept -o flag

Answer (score 0):

You can fake the -o flag, if all you care about is the location, and not the name of the binary. Define `GOBIN` for the install command:

```sh
GOBIN=`readlink -f my/location` go install some/persons/go-package
```

*Caveat*: This doesn't work for cross-compiled binaries.